# Multiplying big numbers to avoid the INF

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a simple factorial function here

```
def _factorial_(n):
    def _generator_(n):
        # Establish a reversed array
        array = np.flip(np.arange(1, n))
        # Convert n into a float
        n = np.float64(n)
        while True:
            # Begin iteration through array
            for i in array:
                # Convert i in to a float
                i = np.float64(i)
                # Multiply values
                n = n*(i)
                # Yield the value
                yield n
            else:
                # At the end of the loop delete the array, and value i
                del array, i
                # Return n
                return n
```

But, when I use it for like a number thats really big I get an INF output, which makes sense but in order for me to do calculations accurately, I need to accurately spit out the numbers rather than lazily labelling big numbers INF.

I tried turning the numbers into floats, and even used the Decimal module to try to convert them into something that was representable but still my function has an overflow limit.

---

```
import array
import struct
from ctypes import c_longdouble

import numpy as np
def bucket(array, size):
    if type(array) != type([]):
        array = list(reversed(np.arange(1,array-1)))
    else:
        array = list(reversed(array))
    
    
        
    bucket = []
    array = [bucket.append(array[i:i+size]) for i in range(0, len(array), size)]
    del array
    
    return (bucket,size)

def factorial(n):
    counter = -1
    size = int(n/2)
    BUCKET,_ = bucket(n,size)
    
    n = float(n*(n-1))
    
    while counter <= len(BUCKET):
        counter+=1
        try:
            
            for numbers in BUCKET[counter]:
                n = memoryview(c_longdouble(n)*c_longdouble(numbers))
                n.cast("L",shape=[1])
                n.tolist()
                
                print(n)

            if counter >= 1:
                BUCKET.pop(0)
                counter = 0
        
            #print(BUCKET)
        
        except Exception:
            return n
            

    return n
```

This is hella slow but im just iterating through stuff getting familiar with python too, uhm I am going to try to implement c though to represent the numbers. I just don't know C

Comment: Showing us a concrete example -- with inputs that accurately represent the largest values you need to work, and code that shows the Decimal approach not working -- would be helpful here. Right now we need to do our own work to plug in numbers in order to test your code, so it isn't as yet a [mre].

Comment: This function uses a lot of tools that don't actually help it do its job. The generator is pointless, as is all the NumPy usage when you're working with a single scalar, and the `if n <= 0` branch doesn't make sense. A straightforward approach using ordinary Python integer arithmetic would be simpler, faster, and not have the overflow problems.

Comment: I believe numpy doesn't use Python's unbounded integer type, it uses fixed-size integers and floats. So if you want unlimited integers, don't use numpy.

Comment: Is your objective to calculate this via recursion and you are working towards that?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can do that np, sorry I made a mistake in the code so I edited it, but here is the update, """x = _factorial(10000) yields -1027359968, when it should be 2.84625968 E+35659 and I think its actually bigger because when I was iterated last night I got infs after that number, the code is different because I accidently shut my pc off without saving but now it yield something completely different, and its a negative.

Comment: @user2357112 numpy is used because its fast to iterate through arrays with numpy.

Comment: @user2357112 you are right though atm it is not a good idea but I do plan on using arrays to perform iterations quicker.

Comment: Part of what _makes_ numpy fast is using native CPU arithmetic operations, and those generally max out at 64-bit data types. Part of what makes Decimal able to handle arbitrarily large numbers is that it _doesn't_ exclusively use native CPU operations. At some point you need to make a binary decision between speed and arbitrarily large numbers; you can't have both at the same time.

Comment: That said -- please edit the details needed to reproduce _into the question_ rather than just adding them in comments; see the [edit] link below the question body, above the beginning of the comment section.

Comment: I don't think `return i` is doing what you hope. What do you actually want to be returned when you call this method? Presumably `_factorial(10)` should return 3628800 not 720 right?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are right, I was just looking into that, but why should I be doing this vs the others?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy import numpy as np
import sys
sys.version
# out: '2.7.3rc2 (default, Mar 22 2012, 04:35:15) \n[GCC 4.6.3]'
np.version.version
# out: '1.6.2'
size = int(1E6)
%timeit for x in range(size): x ** 2
# out: 10 loops, best of 3: 136 ms per loop

%timeit for x in xrange(size): x ** 2
# out: 10 loops, best of 3: 88.9 ms per loop
# avoid this
%timeit for x in np.arange(size): x ** 2
#out: 1 loops, best of 3: 1.16 s per loop
# use this
%timeit np.arange(size) ** 2
#out: 100 loops, best of 3: 19.5 ms per loop

Comment: In general, comments don't work well for multi-line content. Editing the question works a lot better! But if you _must_ put multi-line content into a comment, think about doing some formatting to delimit where each line begins and ends: `first line here` / `second line here` / etc -- in that example, each substring is code-formatted with backticks.

Comment: Anyhow -- yes, CPU-native types are a lot faster, _but if they can't handle your data, that doesn't matter; you can't use them_.

Comment: "numpy is used because its fast to iterate through arrays with numpy" - not with a Python `for` loop! It's only fast for *C* code to iterate over a NumPy array. Iterating over a NumPy array with a Python `for` loop is way slower than iterating over a list. Plus, you don't need to call `numpy.multiply` manually. You can just use `*`. The ufunc exists for more specialized use cases than just calling it to do a multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite follow the logic of your `_factorial()` (edit 2?) particularly as it does not return what I kind of expect even for small values on `n`. For example,

```
print(_factorial(10))
```

returns `720` rather than what I might have expected as `3628800`

Looking at a couple of simple factorial implementations, I might naively do:

```py
def factor(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        result *= i
    return result
```

which seems to work as I expected.

I also did this that uses numpy data types:

```py
def factor_np(n):
    result = numpy.int64(1)
    for i in numpy.arange(numpy.int64(2), numpy.int64(n+1), dtype=numpy.int64):
        result *= i
    return result
```

That also seems to work as I expect but overflows with relatively small values of `n`

for example, n == 100 overflows for the numpy solution:

```py
print(factor(20) == factor_np(20))
print(factor(100) == factor_np(100))
```

So at some level you might need support for larger numpy ints (something my system does not support). However, even with smaller `n`s, numpy does not seem to be doing me any favors.  If I `timeit`:

```py
import timeit

setup = """
import numpy
import math

def factor(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        result *= i
    return result

def factor_np(n):
    result = numpy.int64(1)
    for i in numpy.arange(numpy.int64(2), numpy.int64(n+1), dtype=numpy.int64):
        result *= i
    return result
"""

print(timeit.timeit("factor(20)", setup=setup, number=100_000))
print(timeit.timeit("math.factorial(20)", setup=setup, number=100_000))
print(timeit.timeit("factor_np(20)", setup=setup, number=100_000))
```

I get results like:

```
0.10070950000044832
0.018321600000490434
0.3592790000002424
```

Suggesting to me that numpy here (at least with non-array maths) is the slowest option. The other two (particularly `math.factorial()` are both faster and able to handle "larger" values on `n`.

**Addendum:**

I see that you have a new implementation of `_factorial_()` that does return a result I would expect.  Note those that it is the **slowest** of the alternatives.

```py
import timeit

setup ="""
import numpy
import math

def factor(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        result *= i
    return result

def _factorial_(n):
    def _generator_(n):
        array = numpy.flip(numpy.arange(1,n))
        while True:
            for i in array:
                n = float(n)*float((i))
                yield n
        
            return n
    
    for factorial in _generator_(n):
        factorial=factorial
    
    return factorial
"""

print(timeit.timeit("factor(20)", setup=setup, number=100_000))
print(timeit.timeit("math.factorial(20)", setup=setup, number=100_000))
print(timeit.timeit("_factorial_(20)", setup=setup, number=100_000))
```

giving me:

```
0.10002230000100099
0.017887899997731438
0.5356868999988365
```

with larger `n` of 200:

```
1.4505908000028285
0.24095259999739937
2.9365438999993785
```

**Addendum 2:**

There are suggestions is the comments that:

1. I don't understand how to calculate a factorial
2. I don't understand scientific notation
3. That the exact value of `25! is 155112100433309859840000000000000000000000000`

What is a factorial? What is the value of `4!`?

Factorials are calculated by taking a given number and multiplying it by every number less than it down to 1. Thus 4! is

```
4! === 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
4! === 24
```

It follows that 25! is:

```
25! === 25 * 24 * 23 * ...... * 3 * 2 * 1
```

What is scientific notation?  What does `1.234 * 10^3` mean? Is that the same as `1.234e+3`?

Scientific Notation is a convenient way to express the value of very large and/or very small numbers. It also nicely aligns with the use of floating point math that results in a lack of precision when representing very large or small numbers. Note that `float` in python has a precision of about 18 places sometimes contributing to your invalid exact results. Note: the `decimal` module allows for higher precision.

```
1.234 * 10^3 === 1.234e+3 === 1234
```

Is the value of 25! === `155112100433309859840000000000000000000000000`?

**Absolutely not!** This value overstates the actual value by about 19 orders of magnitude. I don't know where you got that number nor why you are so certain that it correct. I assume one of your attempts produced it and/or it is you that does not understand how to read scientific notation.

In python, numbers can contain `_` for clarity. Let's write that number you insist is the correct value using them, then compare that to other references:

**Your assertion**:

```
155_112_100_433_309_859_840_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000
```

**[coolconversion](https://coolconversion.com/math/factorial/What-is-the-factorial-of_25_%3F)**

```
15_511_210_043_330_985_984_000_000
```

**[thefractioncalculator](https://thefractioncalculator.com/Factorial/What-is-the-factorial-of-25.html)**

```
15_511_210_043_330_985_984_000_000
```

**[convertpedia](https://convertpedia.com.br/en/math/calculate-factorial/25-factorial.php)**

```
15_511_210_043_330_985_984_000_000
```

**`python math.factorial()`**

```
15_511_210_043_330_985_984_000_000
```

**My function**

```py
def factor(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        result *= i
    return result
```

```
15_511_210_043_330_985_984_000_000
```

**Notice a pattern?**

If you still believe your answer of `155_112_100_433_309_859_840_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000` is correct, I recommend you ask for validation on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Please note as well that the python math module specifically optimizes for accuracy and I am certain that if it produced invalid factorials above some easy to test threshold that the developers would have guarded for that.

Finally, here is a table you can ponder. Feel free to check it yourself for accuracy. While time consuming any middle schooler should be able to do the math.:

| n! | Formula | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1! | 1 | 1 |
| 2! | 1! * 2 | 2 |
| 3! | 2! * 3 | 6 |
| 4! | 3! * 4 | 24 |
| 5! | 4! * 5 | 120 |
| 6! | 5! * 6 | 720 |
| 7! | 6! * 7 | 5040 |
| 8! | 7! * 8 | 40320 |
| 9! | 8! * 9 | 362880 |
| 10! | 9! * 10 | 3628800 |
| 11! | 10! * 11 | 39916800 |
| 12! | 11! * 12 | 479001600 |
| 13! | 12! * 13 | 6227020800 |
| 14! | 13! * 14 | 87178291200 |
| 15! | 14! * 15 | 1307674368000 |
| 16! | 15! * 16 | 20922789888000 |
| 17! | 16! * 17 | 355687428096000 |
| 18! | 17! * 18 | 6402373705728000 |
| 19! | 18! * 19 | 121645100408832000 |
| 20! | 19! * 20 | 2432902008176640000 |
| 21! | 20! * 21 | 51090942171709440000 |
| 22! | 21! * 22 | 1124000727777607680000 |
| 23! | 22! * 23 | 25852016738884976640000 |
| 24! | 23! * 24 | 620448401733239439360000 |
| 25! | 24! * 25 | 15511210043330985984000000 |

Let's note one more time for clarity. The correct final result in this table is:

```
15_511_210_043_330_985_984_000_000
```

which is 19 orders of magnitude less than your asserted answer of:

```
155_112_100_433_309_859_840_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000
```

Finally, there is also the assertion that my answer and `math.factorial()` fail for smaller values of `n`. let's try my:

```py
factor(1000)
```

That gives:

```
402387260077093773543702433923003985719374864210714632543799910429938512398629020592044208486969404800479988610197196058631666872994808558901323829669944590997424504087073759918823627727188732519779505950995276120874975462497043601418278094646496291056393887437886487337119181045825783647849977012476632889835955735432513185323958463075557409114262417474349347553428646576611667797396668820291207379143853719588249808126867838374559731746136085379534524221586593201928090878297308431392844403281231558611036976801357304216168747609675871348312025478589320767169132448426236131412508780208000261683151027341827977704784635868170164365024153691398281264810213092761244896359928705114964975419909342221566832572080821333186116811553615836546984046708975602900950537616475847728421889679646244945160765353408198901385442487984959953319101723355556602139450399736280750137837615307127761926849034352625200015888535147331611702103968175921510907788019393178114194545257223865541461062892187960223838971476088506276862967146674697562911234082439208160153780889893964518263243671616762179168909779911903754031274622289988005195444414282012187361745992642956581746628302955570299024324153181617210465832036786906117260158783520751516284225540265170483304226143974286933061690897968482590125458327168226458066526769958652682272807075781391858178889652208164348344825993266043367660176999612831860788386150279465955131156552036093988180612138558600301435694527224206344631797460594682573103790084024432438465657245014402821885252470935190620929023136493273497565513958720559654228749774011413346962715422845862377387538230483865688976461927383814900140767310446640259899490222221765904339901886018566526485061799702356193897017860040811889729918311021171229845901641921068884387121855646124960798722908519296819372388642614839657382291123125024186649353143970137428531926649875337218940694281434118520158014123344828015051399694290153483077644569099073152433278288269864602789864321139083506217095002597389863554277196742822248757586765752344220207573630569498825087968928162753848863396909959826280956121450994871701244516461260379029309120889086942028510640182154399457156805941872748998094254742173582401063677404595741785160829230135358081840096996372524230560855903700624271243416909004153690105933983835777939410970027753472000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

**Which surprise surprise is exactly the same answer that your reference site states for `1000!`**

Comment: 25! is == 155112100433309859840000000000000000000000000, there is no way around that simple fact. You are just mad you got schooled by someone who knows less than you. You legit find it impossible the built in gave you the wrong number, the built in gives you the wrong number because it cant spit out values that big due to memory.

Comment: Look at the page *you* referenced in your answer.  It states clearly that **"25! is exactly: 15511210043330985984000000"** That is your reference not mine.  It also states the floating point approximation of `1.5511210043331E+25` I don't know where you get your number from but it is E+44 or basically absurdly incorrect